# HQL How to process equals for day of week and date without hour,minute,second?

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, hql

Model: Foo

Fields: id(Long), barDate(Date), barDay(Integer 1..7)

Database: Mysql

How to query Foo when barDate is today (without care of hour, minute, second) or barDay is today's day of week?

Could you give me a example by HQL or SQL? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from Foo where date_format(barDate ,'%Y%m%d') = CURDATE()
```